# Save HTML5 page as PDF

Tags: javascript, html

On click of a button, without doing a round trip to the server, can we save a HTML5 page on clients machine as PDF.

Comment: There's no javascript or HTML method for saving PDF files. Your best bet is a server side solution or browser plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [PDF.js](https://github.com/Marak/pdf.js/). This lib can create pdf in the browser (or serverside on node.js).

Answer (score 0):

Using chrome you can print the page to a pdf file.

You need something like this, maybe server-side you can start a browser and print the content to a pdf file and send this to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: i work for ByteScout

If you have simple HTML formatting and want to generate PDF on client side and if you have non-commercial project, check [BytescoutPDF.js](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfgeneratorsdkjs/create_pdf_text_rich_formatting.html) - it supports simple HTML formatting for text (font name, size, color) plus simple drawings and images, should be enough for simple reports